# Dirichlet series generated by $\mu(n) / \phi(n)$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

Let's define
$$ A(s) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\mu(n)}{\phi(n)}n^{-s},$$ i.e. Dirichlet series generated by $\mu(n)/\phi(n)$.

I'm curious whether this Dirichlet series can be represented as other forms, maybe by Riemann zeta function.

Some formula like $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu(n)n^{-s} = 1/\zeta(s)$.

I've been searching for this problem but I'm unable to find good results.

Answer (score 2):

As the coefficients form a multiplicative function, it will have an Euler
product, whose $p$-term is
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{\mu(p)}{\phi(p)}\frac1{p^{ns}}
=1-\frac1{(p-1)p^s}.$$
So
$$A(s)=\prod_p\left(1-\frac1{(p-1)p^s}\right).$$
I can't see very much that I can do with this...

Comment: Thank you for answering.

Comment: Well for $s=1$, your formula gives *Artin's constant*, and for $s=2$, the Euler product formula gives the *quadratic class number constant* (both cited here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_product#Notable_constants). For more general $\Re(s) > 2$, I can express this formula via elementary symmetric polynomials as $$A(s) = \exp\left(\sum_{k \geq 1} \sum_{n \geq 0} \binom{k-1+n}{n} \frac{(-1)^{k+1}}{k} P(n+(s+1)k)\right),$$ where $P(s)$ is the *prime zeta function*.